# GET request in javascript only works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

This request only work with internet explorer,
I've tried many different solutions, for two days I've been trying to make it work and I couldn't . please advise.

pure javascript:

```
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            data = xmlhttp.responseText;
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("p").innerText = data;
         }
       };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=naruto", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic TUFMUTpNTU1xcXExMTEyMjJAQEAjIyM='); 
    xmlhttp.send(null);
```

jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
   url: "http://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=naruto",
   cache: false,
   headers: {"Authorization": "Basic TUFMUTpNTU1xcXExMTEyMjJAQEAjIyM=" ,"Content-Type": "application/xml"},
   method: 'GET',
   dataType: 'xml',
   async: true,
   success: function(data) {
     var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
     var xmlTextNode = document.createTextNode(xmlText);
     var parentDiv = document.getElementById('sdiv');
     parentDiv.appendChild(xmlTextNode);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Perhaps because you are using the non-standard `innerText`? Use `textContent`. Also check your console for errors.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Tried it ,no avail.

Comment: So, what doesn't work? Did you check you developer console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: FTR what version of IE are you talking about?

Comment: @MALQ can you not abandon the question.. what have you done since asking?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is limited to the same domain of your site, because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

You will have to find a way to circumvent it or use AJAX in combination with server-side scripting to get the desired results. If you're going to use something like PHP, you could use something like `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://example.org/search.xml?query"));` but I think you'll also find that the domain in question is using HTTP authentication as well